# Angular-Routing: Using redirectTo redirect to wrong routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In app-routing.module.ts I have the below routings.

When I press on domains ( consider if we have a navigation bar which has domains ) it should display two tabs one for local and one for worldWide and it opens list tab with local/list by default.

My issue is if local/list is opened and when I try to click on worldwide tab the URL is will be /domains/local/worldWide
but I expected it to be /domains/worldWide/list

and vice versa if I'm in worldWide tab and pressed on local tab the URL willbe /domains/worldWide/local but it should be /domains/local/list

How I should do it correctly or what I did wrong?

```
{
    path: 'domains',
    type: 'primary',
    children: [
      {
        type: 'redirect',
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'local',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'local',
        type: 'sub',
        children: [
          {
            type: 'redirect',
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'list',
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: 'list',
            component: LocalDomainsListComponents,
          },
          {
            path: 'form',
            component: LocalDomainsFormComponents,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'worldWide',
        type: 'sub',
        children: [
          {
            type: 'redirect',
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'list',
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: 'list',
            component: WorldWideDomainsListComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'form',
            component: WorldWideDomainsFormComponent,
          },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using router.navigate please?

Comment: tabs (local and worldWide has no router.navigate) but for example LocalDomainsListComponents has route to the LocalDomainsFormComponents like this 
```
router.navigate(['/domains/local/form']
```

Comment: Am not sure how you are using the navigation between the Local and Worldwide tab, for example when you are in local/list and then you hit worldwide, it should go to wordwide/list as per routing module. How are you handling this?
Also please note that router.navigate expects a route to be split into an array. 
You are using router.navigate(['/domains/local/form']) which is not the recommended way. The recommended way is router.navigate(['/', 'domain', 'local', 'form'])
tell a little bit more about how you are handling the switching of tabs. are you using routerLink or router.navigate?

Comment: it is issue with my routerLink thanks for help !